# Unable to change ownership of an opportunity

Tags: opportunity, ownership

Opportunity owner cannot transfer the opportunity to some other person. He is getting error -
"Cannot Share/Transfer Record

You cannot share this record with or transfer to the selected user or group because they cannot view the account associated with this record.
Please ask the owner of the associated account to share the account with the user or group. Then attempt to share or transfer the record again."

Whereas System Administrator can transfer that opportunity to the same person without any issue. Can anyone tell me where the issue is?

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Aritra. Have you enabled manual sharing of records in your org? Does your user have permission to share records with others? Does your org use territories? What Object level permissions does the other user have on Opportunity and any record types that might affect their ability to view the record? These are all things that would be helpful to know in order to answer your question. Please update your question using the [edit link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/221133/edit) at the bottom left of your post. You can edit your question at any time after asking it.

Comment: 1. yes Manual Sharing is enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered this issue recently myself. It has to do with the permissions and relative positions in the role hierarchy of the users that are involved.

When a user obtains View access (which is included, of course, with record ownership) on an Opportunity, they also receive an Implicit Parent Share (read only) to the Opportunity's Account. What's going on here is that the Opportunity Owner has full permissions on the Opportunity, but does not have permission to share the parent Account. Salesforce therefore prohibits the ownership transfer, because the owner doesn't have the right to create that Implicit Parent Share.

The System Administrator has Modify All Data and is likely at the top of the role hierarchy, so he/she has permission to perform this share. The Opportunity's owner would need to be above the Account owner in the role hierarchy, or have similar Modify All permissions, to allow the transfer to go through.

The workaround is for the Account owner, or another user who has full permissions on the Account, to either manually share the Account to the *new* Opportunity owner or to add that user to the Account Team. The ownership transfer will then go through.

Comment: Thanks @David Reed . I also thought of the same reason. However i need to have some more votes on your answer to confirm.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty You can try this for yourself in your own organization. Upvotes don't always mean someone is right!